# Are there any safety or technical reason airlines do not display flight information to passengers in real-time?

Tags: airline-operations, avionics, passenger

A newer addition to commercial airliners is seatback screens, that allow the passengers to watch movies, TV, and so forth. On most airlines, there is also a map, that shows you the aircraft's flight path, position, airspeed, and altitude.

I have noticed that the information displayed on the map screen only updates in roughly 15-second intervals. Is there any reason for this? I can't imagine that there would be any bandwidth limitation issue for such a small amount of text data (for example, I can drive a ton of data to my ForeFlight app with my relatively mid-range GA IFD), so I imagine there must be a safety or technical reason for it.

[image: Seatback Map - JetBlue]

Comment: Is it possible to zoom in on that map?  If not, how many pixels would the icon move in 15 seconds?

Comment: In 15s, the aircraft moves by 2 statute miles

Comment: @DanPichelman With JetBlue, it swapped between three various views - looked like a "US View", to a 500-mile view, to a 250-mile view. Just estimates of course. The map is secondary, I'm more interested in why altitude and speed only update every 15 seconds, as that is simple data.

Comment: It's possible that the source of the data is only updated every 15 seconds

Comment: Do most people really care? If there's no demand (and thus, requirement) for it, the 15~s interval may simply be an arbitrary software value on the airline or OEM's part that seems "about right." They could have simply decided on 2, 5 or 31s and it wouldn't have made any difference. (Okay, maybe 31s is a *bit* long.)

Comment: @aerobot As a pilot, it mattered to me. It also mattered to the other 8 pilots I was traveling with. It's not "needed" information, but it goes along the lines of, why do they give us fre snacks? We're not going to starve inflight, but it's still nice to have. Same applies to the information - it's nice information to know.

Comment: @selectstriker2 I imagine the aircraft's own air data computer should be updating much faster than that, so perhaps it is the entertainment system's computer that updates itself from the air data computer at a much lower rate.

Comment: I haven't designed IFE systems, but as I understand it there is an air gap between the cockpit instruments and the IFE, so they wouldn't be the source of this data. I'd expect something like a standalone GPS system for the IFE system.

Comment: @selectstriker2 TIL. Why the air gap, is the question that now comes to mind. Also sounds like you're on to the beginnings of an answer =)

Comment: @selectstriker2 They transmit data wirelessly though. For example, I can monitor data on my IFD through ForeFlight, and it updates in realtime.

Comment: What possible reason is there for a passenger to see updates more frequently than that? The first question of an aviation system designer is going to be "why should we do this" rather than "why should we not do this".

Comment: @Matt there is a difference between providing additional information to the pilot through an app like ForeFlight and providing information to the general public sitting in the cheap seats.

Comment: @aerobot the reason for the air gap is that one part of the system went through a rigorous (aka expensive) certification process for installation in the aircraft (avionics) and the other system (IFE) does not go through the same process (if any).

Comment: @DJClayworth So you're saying there must be a positive reason for doing anything? Fine. By your own argument, the aviation systems designer must have had a definite reason for choosing the update frequency they did. This question is asking what that reason is.

Comment: @selectstriker2, IFE absolutely goes through a rigorous certification process.  https://www.swissinfo.ch/eng/electrical-fire-downed-swissair-flight-111/3238752

Comment: @MichaelHall true, the IFE system may go through electrical and environmental testing (DO-160) along with the TC/STC work. My point is that the IFE software likely hasn't been through DO-178 and would probably air gapped from the avionics

Comment: @selectstriker2, I can tell you that our stuff absolutely went through DO-178 and 254.  Anything going on a plane needs appropriate rigor, the difference is in the DAL.

Comment: That's good to know. Are IFE systems treated as DAL D or something higher?

Answer (score 8):

If data is continually updated, nervous flyers will fixate on every minor change.

- The altitude changed by 30 ft in one second?
  That is a descent rate of 1,800 FPM!  Surely we're going to crash!
- The speed changed from 480kts to 470kts in one second?
  At this rate, we will stall in less than a minute!
- The plane was at 260kts at 9,800ft?
  This crazy pilot is breaking FAA regulations and must be reported!

By updating less frequently, there is a natural filtering and smoothing of the data to obscure tiny measurement changes due to instrument limitations or conditions like turbulence.

Comment: Definitely possible. Do you have any source to back it up though?

Comment: also it becomes boring too quickly

Comment: 260 at 9800 on the IFE is no problem at all though - the IFE normally only gives ground speed, not indicated :)

Comment: @CptReynolds yes, but it wouldn't stop some pax with too little knowledge from complaining!

Comment: @abelenky I was only nitpicking :) of course! Although actually the (relatively few) people I know who don’t get ground vs. indicated wouldn’t have any clue about 250 below 10.

Comment: @Matt I don't know if the channel 9 live ATC provided by some US airlines still exists, but there are plenty of stories of pax listening in and making complaints when they think the pilot did something wrong. This would be the same, there doesn't need to be a paper to confirm that.

Comment: Actually, I've never seen a flight system that reports KIAS to the passengers. They always report ground speed (usually in kmph or mph), head / tail component of winds aloft, altitude and outside air temperature. One has to do some math to work out the KIAS.

Comment: Nervous fliers don't need flight information to be nervous.  They do not even need to get on the plane.

Answer (score 2):

In flight entertainment systems are designed to be cheap, not good.  Most things in them do not work very well; there is nothing special about the flight information updates.

Most passengers want to watch movies, so that's where the effort is concentrated.

Comment: I think the same people who design inflight systems must also design car infotainment systems. Neither work very well, nothing special about either of them.